# Combining two queries with LIMIT into one

Tags: mysql, sql

I query for 50 articles from "publisher1" then for 50 articles from "publisher2". I combine results to return 100 articles.

I tried combining queries to return result simultaneously without success. Combining would be a performance boost since they each take 150ms. How to combine both queries into one or do I have to query separately?

```
// Query 1
SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher1') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50

// Query 2
SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher2') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50
```

I tried :

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher1') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50 AND SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher2') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "*How to combine both queries into one … ?*"

Using `UNION` :

```
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher1') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher2') ORDER BY datePublished DESC LIMIT 50);
```

Or :

```
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher1') LIMIT 50)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM news WHERE (MATCH(snippet) AGAINST('politics' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) AND (publisher = 'publisher2') LIMIT 50)
ORDER BY datePublished DESC;
```